# Multilocale computation on bigint array

Tags: distributed, bigint, chapel

I'm using Chapel and I'm trying to perform a computation on a `bigint` array in a multilocale setup. A file containing one integer per line is read. Each line is converted to a `bigint` record which is then inserted to a single array. I have 4 locales and I therefore ask each locale to read only 1/4th of the input file and process only that part.

I have reduced my problem to the following minimal example which is also affected:

```
module Hello {

use BigInteger;
use Math;
use Time;

config const inputPath = "/path/to/file";
config const inputSize = 10000000;
config const power = 2000;

proc dwriteln(args ...?n) {
        var curr = getCurrentTime(unit=TimeUnits.seconds);
        writeln("[ ", here.id, ": ", here.name, " ] [ ", curr, " ] ", (...args));
}

proc main() throws {
    writeln("Input path: ", inputPath);
    writeln("numLocales: ", numLocales);

    var elementsPerLocale = divceil(inputSize, numLocales);
    writeln("elementsPerLocale: ", elementsPerLocale);

    coforall loc in Locales {
        on loc {
            dwriteln("hello");
            var inputFile = open(inputPath, iomode.r, hints=IOHINT_CACHED);
            var reader = inputFile.reader();
            var startI = here.id * elementsPerLocale;
            var endI = startI+elementsPerLocale;
            dwriteln("startI = ", startI, " endI= ", endI);

            var a: [1..0] bigint;
            var i = 0;
            for line in reader.lines() {
                    // i in [startI;endI[
                    if i >= startI && i < endI {
                        a.push_back(new bigint(line, 16));
                    }
                    i +=1;
            }

            reader.close();
            inputFile.close();

            dwriteln("created array of size: ", a.size);

            forall elem in a {
                // perform some computation
                elem = elem ** power;
            }
            dwriteln("Computed.");
        }
    }


}


}
```

I expect locales to perform the operations in parallel but this is not the case.

However when running the code it appears that each locale does its processing sequentially. In other words, locale 0 reads the file, does its processing, then locale 1 reads the file and does its processing, and so on. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: I havn't been able to reproduce the problem. I don't see anything wrong with your program, other than that you might want to include 'here.id' in the various writelns in order to see the order things are occurring on the different locales. I tried it with 5 locales on the master branch of Chapel.

Comment: The problem replication is platform-dependent. Would you mind to kindly present also the **`lstopo`** outputs for each of your computing nodes and the actual file-system and file-sizes ( rough scales in `[TB]` ), that you plan to be processed in production? Thank you.

Comment: @mppf I edited the question with slightly modified code so that it prints more debug information and so that the forall loop body does a more CPU intensive operation. So far I'm still seeing the CPU cores at 100% on a single locale at a time for about 5 minutes and then the rest start to wake up and get to 100% CPU usage. By the way, I'm using Gasnet with the UDP conduit. Locales are Openstack VMs and have 10 Gbit/s internal link.

Comment: @zx228 - Did you ever find a solution here? If not, it would be helpful to file this as a GitHub issue for Chapel.

Answer (score 0):

### Chapel grants concurrent & parallel I/O-operations:

> **I/O Overview**
>
> A <kbd>`file`</kbd> in Chapel identifies a file in the underlying operating system. Reads and writes to a file are done via one or more channels associated with the file. Each <kbd>`channel`</kbd> uses a buffer to provide sequential read or write access to its file, optionally starting at an offset.
>
> **[Design Rationale](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/modules/standard/IO.html?highlight=open#design-rationale)**
>
> Since channels operate independently, concurrent I/O to the same open file is possible without contending for locks. Furthermore, since the channel (and not the file) stores the current file offset, it is straightforward to create programs that access the same open file in parallel. Note that such parallel access is not possible in C when multiple threads are using the same FILE* to write to different regions of a file because of the race condition between fseek and fwrite. Because of these issues, Chapel programmers wishing to perform I/O will need to know how to open files as well as create channels.

### Yet, `IO` module details may help to better arrange resources:

As documented,

> The default value of the <kbd>**`iohints`**</kbd> type is undefined.
>   ...
>   `proc open( out
>                 error: syserr,
>                 path:  string = "",
>                 mode:  iomode,
>                 hints: iohints = IOHINT_NONE,
>                 style: iostyle = defaultIOStyle(),
>                 url:   string  = ""
>                 ): file`

Re-run the experiment with non-default, rather explicit setups, where I/O hints better reflect the intended multi-locale processing with ~ **`IOHINT_PARALLEL`**.

Due to the nature of `for line in reader.lines() {...}` ad-hoc iterator, also might be interested in reviewing the experiment's throughput with tweaked `IO` intents with **`IOHINT_CACHED`** and **`IOHINT_SEQUENTIAL`** settings or the `openreader()` **<kbd>`channel`</kbd>** specific instrumentation.

> A value of the iohints type defines a set of hints about the I/O that the file or channel will perform. These hints may be used by the implementation to select optimized versions of the I/O operations.
>
> The  <kbd>`iohints`</kbd> type is implementation-defined. The following  <kbd>`iohints`</kbd> constants are provided:
>
> ```
>   *  IOHINT_NONE       defines an empty set, which provides no hints.
>   *  IOHINT_RANDOM     suggests to expect random access.
>   *  IOHINT_SEQUENTIAL suggests to expect sequential access.
>   *  IOHINT_CACHED     suggests that the file data is or should be cached
>                        in memory, possibly all at once.
>   *  IOHINT_PARALLEL   suggests to expect many channels working with this file
>                        in parallel.
> ```

Comment: In the original question, there is only 1 file object created per locale, and then 1 channel is created to read that file. I don't see how these IO hints help in this case.

Comment: Forcing a single-resource accesses, that is principally a `[SERIAL]` process ( since the very hardware level, arranged as a pure-`[SERIAL]`-ly FAT-described sequence of PHY-media datachunk records ), to happen being read from a set of distributed processes, either in a "just"-`[CONCURRENT]` or even in a true-`[PARALLEL]` manner is definitely both a performance-wise and throughput-wise bad idea. Just recall this is the very **anti-pattern** to the last ~ 40 years industry experience of I/O-access natural-latency masking efforts. If implementation details permit, `IOHINT_CACHED` avoids re-reads.